# Nginx with asp.net backend 404 Error on prod

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, typescript, asp.net-core, nginx

Im running this command to create a publish: `dotnet publish -o "C:\Temp\Feisser" -r linux-arm --self-contained`

I get a bunch of .dll's and the wwwroot folder but if i try to run the index.html manually then it is just blank

[image]

**EDIT:**

If I try to run it via nginx and i start the dotnet project than i get a 404:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://192.168.178.24/ - - - 404 0 - 705.8686ms
```

without the dotnet project i get a 502 from nginx.

and this configuration im using on my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**"/>
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**"/>
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode"/>
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE."/>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..."/>
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install"/>
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod"/>
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**"/>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pay attention to local testing — if you try to load the HTML file locally (i.e. with a file:// URL), you'll run into CORS errors due to JavaScript module security requirements. You need to do your testing through a server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules